# How could I use R studio to simulate a process with a Backshift Operator (Time Series)

Tags: r, time-series

I am fairly new to R, and I am using it for a Time Series course. Please note that this question is not a homework problem. I am wondering how I can use R to simulate a process with a back shift operator. For example, how would I simulate some process X_{t}=2B^{2}Z_{t} (that is, B-squared) where Z_{t} is white noise, and let's say we want to simulate for n=100. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let's get 7 datapoints with an increasing trend.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(time = 1:7,
             B = map_dbl(1:7, ~ runif(1, min = .x, max = (.x + 1))))

# A tibble: 7 x 2
   time     B
  <int> <dbl>
1     1  1.17
2     2  2.04
3     3  3.17
4     4  4.85
5     5  5.87
6     6  6.19
7     7  7.47
```

Z is our random noise.  Backshift is `B^2 + Z`

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Z = runif(nrow(df), -3, 3),
         BackShift = B^2 + Z)

# A tibble: 7 x 4
   time     B      Z BackShift
  <int> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1  1.17  0.317      1.68
2     2  2.04 -2.12       2.03
3     3  3.17  1.91      12.0 
4     4  4.85  2.84      26.4 
5     5  5.87 -0.112     34.4 
6     6  6.19 -2.00      36.3 
7     7  7.47  1.05      56.9
```

Comment: Looking at your code, I see that where you'd had `2B`, I put `B`.  This is the Hamlet problem - `2B | ! 2B`